# How can I use e_tooltip_pie_formatter to convert to percent in tooltip?

Tags: r

I'm creating an interactive pie chart by `echarts4r` for Rshiny apps. seems `e_tooltip_pie_formatter()` is the function to make a unit for value in the tooltip to percent, but I can't make it. Below is sample code on this:

```
library(echarts4r)
a <- c("apple","orange","banana")
b <- c(10,20,25)
c <- data.frame(a,b)
c %>% 
  e_charts(a) %>% 
  e_pie(b, radius=c("50%","70%"))%>% 
  e_tooltip(
   formatter = e_tooltip_pie_formatter("percent")
  )
```

I expect the unit value in the tooltip to be percent, but I still see an absolute number and I am wondering how I can convert it to a percent?

Comment: I don't even see an absolute number when I run your code!!!

Comment: thanks for a confirmation. I checked at myside and I still see absolute number. I also see absolute number even if I go with just e_tooltip(), but I would like to get percentage...

Answer (score 0):

You have to normalize vector b first. For me the following worked:

```
a <- c("apple","orange","banana")
b <- c(10,20,25)
c <- data.frame(a, b = b/sum(b))

c |> e_chart(a) |> e_pie(b) |> e_tooltip(trigger = "item", formatter = e_tooltip_choro_formatter("percent", digits = 2))
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this could be a solution, since it's incomplete.  Your answer starts with a piping operator, so it doesn't seem to include the input dataframe/tibble.  Perhaps this was a copy and paste error from your working solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add a more complete solution. Thanks!